# Authenticating Outlook WEB Add-in with SSO

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to follow the steps for authenticating Outlook WEB Add-in with SSO according to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token#updating-the-add-in-manifest), but got stuck at the section **Updating the add-in manifest**. Described in [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#configure-the-add-in), I have to add this piece in the VersionOverrides section of the manifest file:

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
  <Id>912344b-661c-4424-0ksc-fb23131aa2e344</Id>
  <Resource>api://localhost:44374/912344b-661c-4424-0ksc-fb23131aa2e344</Resource>
  <Scopes>
    <Scope>profile</Scope>
    <Scope>user.read</Scope>
  </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

and also change the version from *VersionOverridesV1_0* to *VersionOverridesV1_1*, because my WEB Add-in is for Outlook (WEB). I change that in the manifest in Visual Studio, but for some reason it gives me this error message:

> This is an invalid xsi:type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides:VersionOverridesV1_1'

Why?

EDIT: I stumbled across [this](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/versionoverrides?product=outlook) where it says:

> Note: Currently only Outlook 2016 supports the VersionOverrides v1.1 schema and the VersionOverridesV1_1 type.

but my Add-in is Web and not for native client... Therefore how to add this *WebApplicationInfo* section, when the *VersionOverridesV1_0* does not support it and proceed with the next steps from the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VersionOverridesV1_1` should be a *child* of `VersionOverridesV1_0`, it is not an either-or. From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/versionoverrides#implementing-multiple-versions):

> In order to implement multiple versions, the `VersionOverrides` element for the newer version **must be a child of** the `VersionOverrides` element for the older version. The child `VersionOverrides` element doesn't inherit any values from the parent.

```xml
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Description resid="" />
    <Requirements>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
    </Resources>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <Description resid="" />
        <Requirements>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
```

Comment: Adding to Marc's answer, if you are only using the version overrides 1.1 section, you can omit the other child elements (Description, Requirements, etc.) from the version overrides 1.0 element (so version overrides 1.1 would be the only child of version overrides 1.0).